# How can I ignore horizontally QWheelEvent?(for mouse pad)

Tags: c++, qt, zooming

I use QWheelEvent for zoom in/out on GraphicsScene but the problem is that zoom in/out is also working when I use mouse pad horizontally. I want to ignore this situation. I want to do zoom in/out on mouse pad just vertically.

My code is:

```
`void WheeledGraphicsView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event){
        setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse);
        double scaleFactor = 1.15;
        if(event->delta() > 0) {
            scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
        }
        else {
            scale(1.0 / scaleFactor, 1.0 / scaleFactor);
        }
       // QWheelEvent.orientation();
}
`
```

maybe I can use QWheelEvent::orientation() but I couldn't use it.
thank you !

---

I solved the problem like this:

```
WheeledGraphicsView::WheeledGraphicsView(QWidget *parent) : QGraphicsView(parent){

}

void WheeledGraphicsView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event){
    if(event->orientation() == Qt::Horizontal) {
        event->ignore();
    }
    else {
        if(event->delta() > 0) {
            scale(ZOOM_RATIO_PER_WHEEL_TICK, ZOOM_RATIO_PER_WHEEL_TICK);
        }
        else {
            scale(1.0 / ZOOM_RATIO_PER_WHEEL_TICK, 1.0 / ZOOM_RATIO_PER_WHEEL_TICK);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What Qt version are you using? In Qt 5 the QWheelEvent has the angleDelta() or pixelDelta() methods that return a point, so that you can get the x delta or the y delta

Comment: I use Qt 5.7 but how can I ignore wheelevent horizontally with angleDelta() or pixelDelta()? Could you help me for writing code?

Comment: Please do not submit answers by editing them into the question.

Comment: Horizontal: pixelDelta().x() !=0 and Vertical: pixelDelta().y() !=0